# Is there a spring batch pattern to persist the unaltered values before the ItemProcessor is called?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

Desired step flow:
[image: Desired step flow]

The expectation is that in the scope of a single XA transaction, the step will:

1. Select the partitioned data
2. Write the **unaltered** partitioned data to an audit table (redo log) using the JDBC BatchUpdate
3. invoke the ItemProcessor on the **unaltered** data
4. use a composite writer to batch write additonal operations to additional targets

The puzzle I am trying to solve is that the process needs to read the partition once only, and operate strictly within the bounds of that selection.

If there is no "wiretap" configuration to accomplish this, a solution I am considering  is to implement the batch write to the redo log in the reader itself, but that just feels ugly, like it defeats the purpose of the framework. If there is already a spring batch pattern for this it would be much better.

We are using the spring batch XML definitions because it gives a degree of control over bean scoping that the DSL does not permit.

Since spring integration is already a part of this project for other functions, another option might be to refactor this as a spring integration flow.

---

**(Edit 3: Notes about answers)**

Both Artem and Mahmoud's answers are correct. I have fleshed out designs for both scenarios, far beyond what is shown on this question. I wish I could flag them both as correct, so make sure to upvote Artem's answer and give him due credit.

The advantage to Artem's answer is that, with a little refactoring of existing code I could eliminate the spring batch from the worker side of the architecture, and reduce our code to simplify some other operations that are not referenced in this question.  The disadvantage is it would require a much more major refactoring and addressing a learning curve that is simply huge.

The biggest advantage to Mahmoud's answer is specific to my case: I can implement it with code paradigms that are already familiar to my team and are already core to the existing product.

Both should be nearly equally efficient. I would actually have to implement both to measure efficiency.

In the context of my project, I have elected to follow Mahmoud's answer because it requires the least changes to the current design and code paradigm.

---

**(Edit: alternative flow build in Spring Integration)**

Based on comments from @Artem Bilan, I have started a design to refactor to Spring Integration.
Not visible:

- flows and flow elements are created dynamically at runtime by a rules engine, and destroyed when no longer in use
- each flow encompasses a chain of readers that may or may not be JDBC

[image: alternative flow build in Spring Integration]

**(Edit 2: Refinement of spring batch architecture)**

Based on comments from Mahmoud Ben Hassine, there are Listener hooks we can leverage. The refined graphic shows the ItemProcessListener being used for both audit requirements, although this is not necessarily the final code we will use.

[image: Refined steps Spring Batch]

Any thoughts or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such audit requirements can be implemented using listeners. The `ItemProcessListener`, and the similar `ItemReadListener` and `ItemWriteListener`, are the injection points that allow you to plug custom code before/after each phase of the chunk-oriented processing model.

So for your use case, I would keep it simple and use a `ItemProcessListener#beforeProcess(T item)` to persist/log the "unaltered" items.

Comment: This is so obvious I facepalmed. The Spring Batch framework is incredibly rich and I'm not sure I have to bandwidth to fully grasp it.

Answer (score 1):

You may implement such a scope with Spring Integration `@MessagingGateway`, where its gateway method can be marked with a `@Transactional`. As long as an integration flow subscribed to the request channel is built with `DirectChannel` in between endpoints, the whole process will be performed within that transaction.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway

Comment: I'm not clear from this response - are you suggesting that a complete refactoring under the spring integration paradigm is the best way to approach this, or is there a way to incorporate this into the existing Spring Batch step?  I'm open either way, but I want to understand before jumping in and committing to one path over the other.

Comment: I'm not so good with Spring Batch, but you have asked about possible solution via Spring Integration. Spring Batch has a respective integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#springBatchIntegration

Comment: That clarifies.  On review, I have a similar spring integration flow already in my product that can give me a start in the right direction (so the refactoring is not as huge as it might otherwise be).  In you experience, what might be the tradeoffs of doing this in a spring integration flow versus batch?

Comment: The integration flow is stateless unlike batch job, so I'd recommend still keep batch as a top-level initiator and call an integration flow as a part of a step if it is too hard to express a logic via just tasklets.

Comment: I've reviewed our existing steps that incorporate spring integration, and pulled together what I think our flow needs to look like.  Is this close to what you were thinking of?

Comment: That one is very business-specific, but if it makes sense for you and works, then it is fully OK to go that direction.

Comment: What isn't visible here is the UI, rules engine, and factories that configure the flow elements. Once configured, the only business goal for this phase of the process is to execute as efficiently and robustly as possible. The technical goal is to be as simple and maintainable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this in spring batch would be to create your own ItemWriter that processes the items before writing them, similar to this...

```java
public class ItemProcessorAndWriter<I, O> implements ItemWriter<I> {

    private final ItemProcessor<I, O> itemProcessor;

    private final ItemWriter<O> itemWriter;

    public ItemProcessorAndWriter(ItemProcessor<I, O> itemProcessor, ItemWriter<O> itemWriter) {
        this.itemProcessor = itemProcessor;
        this.itemWriter = itemWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends I> items) throws Exception {

        List<O> processedItems = new ArrayList<>(items.size());
        for (I item : items) {
            processedItems.add(itemProcessor.process(item));
        }

        itemWriter.write(processedItems);
    }

}
```

you could then create a CompositeItemWriter that would contain your Audit writer first, followed by the ItemProcessorAndWriter that does the item processing and writing.

Comment: This is what we have today. The problem presented in this question is a serious(!) oversimplifcation of one aspect of the entire problem. What I'm trying to do is leverage the Spring batch model, and get away from the limitations and extra coding that our current processing model has today.